# Inconsistent accessibility parameter type error while Injecting Service to Controller-Constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control

while Injecting Service to Controller shows error                         "Inconsistent accessibility:parametertype 'IProductRepository' is less accessible than method 'ProductController.ProductController(IProductRepository)'"

Tools/Framework used: visualstudio_2015,mvc 4.6,and unity_Container_4

i am very new to this "IoC" , i guess i am missing something

### Error code

```
private IProductRepository _IobjProductRepository;
//error shown in this code part
 Injecting Service to Controller shows error -->
public ProductController(IProductRepository Repository)
 { _IobjProductRepository = Repository;} 
 <--error shown in this code par
```

t

### BootStrapcode

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
      var container = new UnityContainer();
      container.RegisterType<IProductRepository,ProductRepository>();
      container.RegisterType<IController,ProductController>();
            // register all your components with the container here
            // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

            // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();  
            // MvcUnityContainer.Container = container;

            RegisterTypes(container);  
            return container;
    }
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container){}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make your `IProductRepository` a public interface.

```
public interface IProductRepository 
{
  // your properties & methods
}
```